# find the number of times for calling a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use MATLAB in order to know for every single time that a function is called, Matlab returns a specific value.what kind of command i can use that do this for me.
for example for first call return 1000 and for second time return 2000.

Comment: why not just log it to a text file? It would help if you could provide some context for why you want to do this?

Comment: Or increment a global variable...

Comment: The method used can depend on the purpose, if you want to know for optimization reasons the profiler would give the number of function call plus a lot more information. If you have recursive functions, the function can have a counter as input, that increases with 1 each time the function is called. If you want to know how many times a function is called for other reasons than optimization or if the function is not recursive, then dragging around a variable is cumbersome and then the solution proposed by @Dan is maybe better.

Comment: @Dev-iL a global variable will work, but is tedious. If a global variable is used, then make sure to give it a name that will stay unique like `globalMyFunCounter` or so.

Comment: i am trying to use genetic algorithm in Matlab app in order to solve an optimization problem.i dont have the fittness function.what i have is a model from Vensim software.population enter to the vensim model and the output is fitness function.

Comment: @patrik - I fail to see how writing this information to a file is a better solution than updating a global variable. It is highly unlikely that I/O operations are less time consuming than an update of a variable in memory.

Comment: I am trying to use genetic algorithm in Matlab app in order to solve an optimization problem.i don't have the fitness function.what i have is a model from Vensim software.population enter to the Vensim model and the output is fitness function.we have 10 chromosome that have 10 value for fitness function.what kind of commands we can use in Matlab that match each fitness value with its own chromosome.

Comment: @Dev-iL I think that you are right. I am not opposed your solution. I am sorry if it sounded that way. What I meant was that a global variable solves the problem, but that care need to be taken to not mess it up. For example it would not be to good to define `global k = 0;` in the beginning. The current writer will know that `k` is then reserved, but if there are many writers, that variable may already have been taken and this in a function that the current writer have never seen.

Comment: OP: please use the `edit` button instead of posting additional comments.
@patrik - don't worry about it. What you say makes a lot of sense - I, too, was warned extensively in my first programming course to avoid the use of `global` variables when possible (for the reason that they are easy to mess up).

Answer (score 2):

Try with the profiler. You will know the number of times that a function is called and the time that has taken.

In the main function:

```
profile on
```

To stop it:

```
profile off
```

And to show the statistics:

```
profile viewer
```

Hope it helps!